# Django - Why am I getting an IndexError when asking for the first item in the list after ensuring the list exists?

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what I might be doing wrong.

the html

```
if follows_answers.exists():
    previous_question = follows_answers[0].question
else:
    previous_question = current_question.follows_question.all()[0]
```

the relevant traceback

```
/srv/local/quizapp/quiz/views.py in previous_question_url
       277. previous_question = follows_answers[0].question

Local Vars

Variable    
follows_answers   [<Answer: Blue>]

/home/quizapp/.virtualenvs/quizapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __getitem__
        return list(qs)[0]

Local Vars

Variable
qs                []
k                 0
self              [<Answer: Blue>]
```

Comment: Can an empty box exist?

Comment: follows_answers is a queryset and no, it won't exist if it's empty.  Also, it shows in the debug toolbar that follows_answers isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

QuerySets are lazily evaluated, maybe the list transformation isn't triggering the evaluation. Try explicitly `follows_answers.all()[0].question` instead.